# Child theme: modification of a file

Tags: wordpress-theming

WordPress 5.2.4
Theme NewsMag Lite.

I've created a child theme. The function that I'd like to modify in the parent theme is located here:

..\wp-content\themes\newsmag\inc\libraries\class-newsmag-sidebars.php

I have copied it like this:

..\wp-content\themes\newsmag-child\inc\libraries\class-newsmag-sidebars.php

Then modified the desired function a bit. No effect.

Well, it seems that the copied file is not used. Could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don`t know that theme but in many cases you can copy the php-function to your child themes functions.php.

Regards Tom